# Concatenating Two Integers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, integer, concatenation

It might be the simplest Question, but at this time ,I am not getting any Idea on how to implement this.

Ok, The problem is of how to concatenate two integers.

**For Eg:** I want to create an integer say **0000** using two different integers **00** and **00**. I tried using **NSString** , but I failed.

**My Code is :**

```
                int num1 = 00;
                int num2 = 00;
                NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",num1,num2];
                int num = [str intValue];
                NSLog(@"num = %d",num); // It Logs 0 but I want 0000.
```

Does anyone have better Idea ?

**EDIT :**

Please Note that , I want to use that **num** to set the **tag** of **textfield**. That's why all the **zeros** are essential. So my main Problem starts here.

I have one **tableview** which contains custom cells. This **custom cell** has **more than 10** textfields. Now I want to uniquely identify all the **textfields** for editing. That's why the **tag** for that textfield must be the integer concatenated by two values called **rowNumber** and **textFieldNumber** (means which textField out of 10.).

So my question is what I am trying to do is right or not ? And if not then give me some useful solution.

Comment: What is the difference between 0000, 00 and just 0 when you treat them as integers? What are you really looking for?

Comment: well, when you are converting `@"0000"` to integer, it takes 0000=0. this will always be a special case. Why don't you use the string `str` itself?

Comment: I want to use that integer to set the tag of textfield.

Comment: that won't work. UIView tags are integers, so 0000 is the same tag as 0.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer data types (such as `int`) only store the integer value, not formatting information. Therefore you lose the number of leading zeroes (which do not affect the integer value, i.e., 0, 00, and 0000 are the same integer: zero).

If you wish to retain formatting information, you must store it separately. A simple way is to just store the string itself. Or, if you always want to have the same number of digits, then alter the formatting string:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d%02d",num1,num2];
```

After the above code, `str` will be `"0000"`. However, converting it to `int` and then logging with `%d` formatting results in `0` once more (since 0000 and 0 are the same integer).

**Edit**: For the purpose of generating unique integers for tagging purposes, given a row number (`rowNumber`) and text field number (`textFieldNumber`), use a formula like:

```
tagNumber = rowNumber * 100 + textFieldNumber;
```

This way the text fields of row 0 will have numbers 0..99, those on row 1 will have 100..199, etc. If more than 100 text fields are required per row, simply multiply by a larger number, like 1000.

In integer arithmetic these values can be converted back to row and field numbers with:

```
 rowNumber = tagNumber / 100;
 textFieldNumber = tagNumber % 100;
```

Comment: I want to use this num to set the tag of textfield , that's why i want all the zeros to uniquely identify all the textfields.

Comment: @BhavinChitroda Why don't you tag the textfields with different numbers then, e.g., 0, 1, 2, …?

Comment: Textfields are in tableview which has custom cells and each cell has around 10 textfields. So to keep track of all the textfields , I need row number and textfield number to store in the tag field. i think so.  Hope you understand.

Comment: @BhavinChitroda How about `rowNumber * 100 + textFieldNumber`?

Comment: suppose my textfieldnumber is greater than 10 then is there any chance for collision ?

Comment: No, only if `textFieldNumber` > 99; row 0 has numbers 0…99, row 1 has numbers 100…199, etc. Of course you can change the formula at will, e.g., `rowNumber * 1000 + textFieldNumber` gives you space for 1000 text fields (0…999) per row.

Comment: Gr8.. Some relief for me. +1 for you. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3=0;
int num4=0;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d",num1,num2,num2,num3];
int num = [str intValue];
NSLog(@"num = %0*d",str.length,num);
```

Hope this helps you.

but dont init as like this "int num1=00" because it init "0" only in num1.

Answer (score 0):

Why turn it back into an int? You should print the string you just formatted:

```
NSLog(@"num = %@",str);
```

As numbers, there is no difference between 0 and 0000. Integers only preserve the value, not the formatting (that's what strings are for).

Comment: But i want to store it as an integer.

Comment: as i think it should be possible with NSString only not with int.

Comment: you can't, 0000 isn't an integer

Comment: 0000 is an integer, but the same integer as 0.

Comment: I want to use that integer to set the tag of textfield. and i require all these zeros for unique identification of textfield.

Comment: that won't work. UIView tags are integers, so 0000 is the same tag as 0.

Comment: So do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: If it's always four digits, you could add 10000. So 00+00 => 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first integer with 100 and add the second integer to it. You should be able to print it using:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", sum]);
```

which will put leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can pad it as :

NOTE: both the num1 and num2 must be of 2 digits. If its size increases then it wont work.

```
int num1 = 00;
int num2 = 00;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",num1,num2];
int num = [str intValue];
NSLog(@"num = %04d",num);
```

Comment: both numbers may go to 00 to 99. Is it still work ?

Comment: Then my code will  "daudega" (work like charm). for 99 and 99 it will show 9999, If this is your requirement

Comment: If i want to store 0000 for tag of textfield then... ? (I think it will store 0 as tag value, isn't it.)

Comment: no...it will store 0000.

Answer (score 0):

If printing is not the real issue then i guess you need a multiplication factor to set the tag
let it be 10000 and add it to some sequence no to get the unique tag value.

or you can use num as string and multiply by 10 in for loop for num.length times